# Does audio embed not work anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Is it still possible to embed audio by adding the appropriate meta tags? I'm trying by using og:audio, og:audio:type, and og:image .  This is just sitting on some web page not tied to anything having to do with a Facebook app or open graph actions. When I paste the link into my status update, all the tagged data shows up: title, image, description, but the Facebook audio player never embeds the url i put into og:audio

Answer (score 1):

Are you a whitelisted partner ? The documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/ says it's currently available only to whitelisted partners.

Comment: is there a query whitelisting?